# Handlebars: Compile variable value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Using handlebars, I want to display the value of the variable `description` using the following template:

```
{{description}}
```

Giving the description variable value:

```
My description and {{myhelper}}
```

How can I update my template so that myhelper (Which is a custom helper) is executed when {{description}} is compiled?

Actually it renders like this:

```
My description and {{myhelper}}
```

I want it to render like

```
My description and helper result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate helpers using parenthesis.

Not knowing the implementation of your helpers i can only guess that you can achieve your wanted results with something like this:

```
{{description (myhelper)}}
```

equivalent to a function call `description(myhelper())`